# Wordy explanations to questions given details

Tags: text-generation

Consider simple details like this: Actor: Brad Pitt Age: 60 And a simple question like this: Question: How old is Brad Pit?

I want to do this all on my pc, preferably with the transformers library.

I want to use an existing model to take in the question and the details and return a nicely worded response of some given length. Is this possible with some existing model?

I tried GPT 2 but was laughably bad.